# How can I transform this Code with Joins instead of using +(=) or =

Tags: sql, sql-server

1. I was trying Hours to transform this code(I think It is Oracle) with joins in SQL Server instead of
2. using  +(=)/= but somehow i dont get the same result as using += or =. Can please someone help me out ?

```
SELECT KNVV.MANDT, KNVV.KUNNR, 
       KNVV.VTWEG, KNVV.BZIRK, KNVP.KUNN2
 FROM  KNA1, KNVV, KNVP, CDHDR
 WHERE 
       AND `(KNVV.MANDT = KNA1.MANDT`
       AND `KNVV.KUNNR = KNA1.KUNNR)`
       AND `(KNVP.MANDT (+) = KNVV.MANDT`
       AND `KNVP.KUNNR (+) = KNVV.KUNNR`
       AND `KNVP.VTWEG (+) = KNVV.VTWEG)`
       AND `(CDHDR.MANDANT (+) = KNVV.MANDT`
       AND `CDHDR.OBJECTID (+) = KNVV.KUNNR)`
       AND `(KNVV.VTWEG = KNVP.VTWEG)`
       AND `KNVP.PARVW (+) = 'RG'`
       AND CDHDR.OBJECTCLAS (+) = 'DEBI'
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you *really* using SQL Server or Oracle? Also, why are you *still* using that ancient join syntax? It was superseded almost 30 years ago.

Comment: Either LEFT or RIGHT JOIN.

Comment: The `(+)` is on the side of the table that can return null rows.

Comment: @Larnu Hi, I am using Microsoft SQL Server and this ancient join syntax is used in SAP ERP for a txt. export.

Answer (score 2):

Without sample data its hard to test but it appears you want:

```sql
SELECT KNVV.MANDT, KNVV.KUNNR, 
       KNVV.VTWEG, KNVV.BZIRK, KNVP.KUNN2
 FROM  KNA1
       INNER JOIN KNVV
       ON (   KNVV.MANDT = KNA1.MANDT
          AND KNVV.KUNNR = KNA1.KUNNR
          )
       INNER JOIN KNVP
       ON (   KNVP.MANDT = KNVV.MANDT
          AND KNVP.KUNNR = KNVV.KUNNR
          AND KNVP.VTWEG = KNVV.VTWEG
          AND KNVV.VTWEG = KNVP.VTWEG -- This duplicated condition makes it an
                                      -- INNER JOIN and not a LEFT OUTER JOIN as
                                      -- you are not using (+) in Oracle's legacy
                                      -- syntax.
          AND KNVP.PARVW = 'RG'
          )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN CDHDR
       ON (   CDHDR.MANDANT    = KNVV.MANDT
          AND CDHDR.OBJECTID   = KNVV.KUNNR
          AND CDHDR.OBJECTCLAS = 'DEBI'
          )
```

What you probably want is to make the second join a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN` but that is not what your current query is doing as you are using `(KNVV.VTWEG = KNVP.VTWEG)` rather than `(KNVV.VTWEG = (+) KNVP.VTWEG)` in your Oracle query.

Answer (score 0):

You query can be converted to:

```
select
  KNVV.MANDT, 
  KNVV.KUNNR, 
  KNVV.VTWEG, 
  KNVV.BZIRK, 
  KNVP.KUNN2
from KNA1
join KNVV on KNVV.MANDT = KNA1.MANDT
         and KNVV.KUNNR = KNA1.KUNNR
left join KNVP on KNVP.MANDT = KNVV.MANDT -- left join defeated!
              and KNVP.KUNNR = KNVV.KUNNR
              and KNVP.VTWEG = KNVV.VTWEG
              and KNVP.PARVW = 'RG'
left join CDHDR on CDHDR.MANDANT = KNVV.MANDT
               and CDHDR.OBJECTID = KNVV.KUNNR
               and CDHDR.OBJECTCLAS = 'DEBI'  
where KNVV.VTWEG = KNVP.VTWEG -- silently converts left join into inner join
```

**NOTE: the original query is malformed**

Even though the original query tried to perform a left join against the table `KNVP` this join is silently converted into an inner join by the engine. Are you sure this query is working as expected?

Comment: `KNVP.PARVW = 'RG'` appears to be in the wrong join condition.

Comment: @MT0 Good catch! fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try inner JOIN?

```
SELECT KNVV.MANDT, KNVV.KUNNR, 
   KNVV.VTWEG, KNVV.BZIRK, KNVP.KUNN2
FROM KNA1, KNVV, KNVP, CDHDR
INNER JOIN KNVV ON KNA1.MANDT=KNVV.MANDT;
```

Something in this sense its more convenient.
documentation bellow
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: `(+) =` is LEFT or RIGHT JOIN - can't remember which.

Comment: It Is Left Join I think :)